# Use a TypeScript generic function in React to pass on a ref

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a simple wrapper component in React:

```
import React, { ComponentProps } from 'react'

const SomeWrapper = <C extends 'div' | 'a'>(Comp: C, ref: ComponentProps<C>['ref']) => {
  return <Comp ref={ref} />
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecDCE4EAdkiTAApQRgDOcAvnAGY0hwDkUqGnAUPzSk68AMpEkAdSgowYJFDgBeOAB58cJAA8Y5ACYNO+4ADdOcAD5cUnAHwAKQuABcBbDxZvnkMhWq0dBp2ANrcSCycALoAlCp2uPxwcDwwAK5QJOo+KRHKOJ7MAPR2-IxAA)

It looks like the inferred value of `ref` ends up being a proper union, but for some reason the prop `Component.ref` is typed as an intersection. I'm not sure why.

I assumed this would work, since the `Comp` and `ref` arguments both come from the generic type, but that doesn't seem to work.

Note: I know that the `forwardRef` is usually used for this situation. This is not my actual use-case, this is a bare-minimum reproduction of the issue at hand. I'm not looking for suggestions of other ways to handle forwarding the `ref`.